# Boolean given (Trying to display statistics about database table)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display statistics of my database table. I have a column called topics and it contains different values and then a column called priority which contains fields with values between 1-10.

Now, what I would like to do is display statistics for this table in the following format.

xx of the priority "1" have the topic "xxxxxx" as topic.
xx of the priority "1" have the topic "yyyyyy" as topic.
xx of the priority "1" have the topic "zzzzzz" as topic.
xx of the priority "2" have the topic "xxxxxx" as topic.
xx of the priority "2" have the topic "yyyyyy" as topic.
xx of the priority "2" have the topic "zzzzzz" as topic.

And so on.

I have the following code but it is returning a "
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given" error when I try to use it.

```
<?php
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "dbname";

    $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database);

$sql = "
       SELECT priority, COUNT(priority) as nbr_of_priorities, topic, 
       FROM table_Name
       GROUP BY priority, topic
    ";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
         echo $row['nbr_of_priorities'].'of the priority'.$row['priority'];
         echo 'has'.$row['topic'].'as topic';
}
?>
```

Comment: You should really move away from `mysql_*` and start using PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: ok, but this is just for backend, private use. Right now its not working and I should not focus on improving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run your query against the DB?

I see an erroneous comma in your SQL, after "topic"... your query could be failing, then $results would be false (which you are not testing), then your while would fail with that error...

Comment: That worked! It was the comma. Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as I can.